# how to validate a form that has only checkboxes/buttons/selects?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with ONLY checkboxes, selects, and radio buttons. The output will depend on the combination of these different inputs. So if I have 2 of each then I would have 2^6(might be wrong) different choices. How do I get the inputs without using if statements?

The way I'm thinking is basically checking each input(using ifs) then somehow get the proper output. But I don't think that's not a good idea.

Maybe validate is a bad word?

Comment: We need some code. Lets see what you've already done. This will help us answer your question.

Comment: Please give us at least your HTML code with input elements.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you asking us how to be lazier? No problem, that's what coding is about. :)

Comment: @Christian not lazier, smarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you loop through the collection of elements and based on the element type, or class name, you apply a set of rules. You don't need to validate each individual form field on its own.

Comment: i honestly dont see any other way than to use if statements. i tried to do some hashing or using a binary scheme, but eventually it will come back to using tons of ifs...